# Mac OS boost installed using macports collision with C++ version

Tags: c++, macos, boost, clang, macports

Anyone know why `sudo cmake --build ./build-clang --config Release` results in

```
In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp:29:
/opt/local/include/boost/asio/detail/type_traits.hpp:89:12: error: no member named 'result_of' in namespace 'std'
using std::result_of;
      ~~~~~^
```

Despite the env variables being set?

```
$CC=clang
$CXX=clang++
```

`$CC --version`

```
Homebrew clang version 15.0.6
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
```

trying to build for Mac for the first time.
boost was installed using macports `sudo port install boost +universal`

---

I've heard result_of was deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20 – how can I get around this issue? I'm working with C++20

---

when I add

```
target_compile_definitions(${TARGET_NAME}
        PRIVATE
        BOOST_ASIO_HAS_STD_INVOKE_RESULT=1)
```

I get the same errors

---

I uninstalled and reinstalled the latest version using `brew` and now I get `/opt/local/include/cpprest/http_client.h:68:10: fatal error: 'boost/asio/ssl.hpp' file not found #include "boost/asio/ssl.hpp"`

Comment: Note [`result_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) is deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Do you know how I can reinstall boost for C++20 support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that at the moment, [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/boost/details/) only supports up to ***Boost 1.76***. By default, it will use [`std::result_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of), which has been removed in C++20.

To solve this, you can manually define `BOOST_ASIO_HAS_STD_INVOKE_RESULT`, which should route usages of `result_of` to the C++20 compliant `invoke_result` within the source.

<sub>Note, this does not guarantee all other codes are C++20 compliant.</sub>

---

Alternatively, you can also manually install Boost, or install it through other package managers like [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/boost#default), which supports up to ***Boost 1.81***

Comment: Thanks - I'll try this out. I didn't realise the version of boost was outdated, without native support for C++20

Comment: when I add `target_compile_definitions(${TARGET_NAME}         PRIVATE         BOOST_ASIO_HAS_STD_INVOKE_RESULT=1)` I get the same errors

Comment: Does boost also support universal builds like macports?

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled the latest version using `brew` and now I get `/opt/local/include/cpprest/http_client.h:68:10: fatal error: 'boost/asio/ssl.hpp' file not found
#include "boost/asio/ssl.hpp"`

Comment: @Tobiq *'when I add ... I get the same errors'* -- Did you get the exact same error, including where the error happened?

Comment: @Tobiq *'I reinstalled the latest version using `brew`...'* -- Is your `cpprest` installed with MacPorts? You might need to manually add the include path to your build system.

Comment: Yes same error after setting up the macro.
And I reconfigured the cmake project and it finds the newly installed brew boost - still fails to compile.